# Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [Employee]

Tags: java, hibernate, classnotfound

I am writing a simple Hibernate program on Eclipse. I did everything steps by steps but then after compiling its showing:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [Employee]

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : Employee
```

I added all the required jar library too.

This is my project structure: 
[image: here]

Comment: *Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException*

Comment: Could you please show me your Employee class and how did  you create the hibernate session to persist Employee objects?

Answer (score 3):

Check this entry in hibernate config file. May be you have changed the package name and forgot to change the reference in config file.

```
<mapping class="Package of employee class"/>
```

Also change the tag of mapping resource to mapping class, and see if it works.

Comment: I had the same issue as the OP and just forgot to update the configuration xml file. +1 for answering to a question which is not clear and doesn't explicitly define the problem.

Comment: @Manoj, he is not using any annotated class mapping, he is using resource mapping, you can't make him change his mapping

Answer (score 2):

**Using resource mapping**

As you are using a mapping resource, the problem is with class path mentioned in your `emp.hbm.xml`, as you have `Employee.java` inside the package `hibernatetutorial1` your class path will be `hibernatetutorial1.Employee`. So you need to mention this in your `emp.hbm.xml`

```
//emp.hbm.xml
<hibernate-mapping>  
  <class name="hibernatetutorial1.Employee" table="tablename">  
  .......
  .......
</hibernate-mapping>
```

and map this resource inside `Hibernate.cfg.xml`

```
//Hibernate.cfg.xml
<hibernate-configuration>  
    <session-factory>  
    ......
    ......
    ......
    <mapping resource="emp.hbm.xml"/>  
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**Using annotated class mapping**

It's better using annotated classes as they decrease your burden, if you are using annotated class then you need to mention your classpath inside `Hibernate.cfg.xml` and you need to use mapping class, no need of mapping resource

```
//using annotated class mapping no need of emp.hbm.xml(resource mapping)
//Hibernate.cfg.xml
<hibernate-configuration>  
    <session-factory>  
        ......
        ......
        ......
    <mapping class="hibernatetutorial1.Employee"/>  
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: this helped me a lot. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This may help to those who uses springboot or deal with queries

This exception may trigger when in somewhere you used by package path which is invalid, for example, in this query:

```
@Query("SELECT new my.com.scicom.esd.testservice.model.document.TestClassLite(his.docEntry, his.id, his.fieldOrSection, his.oldValue, his.newValue, his.modifiedBy, his.modifiedOn) "
        + " FROM TestClass his"
        + " WHERE his.name = :name"
)
```

In here double check that you have given the right path(Package wise) :

```
my.com.esd.testservice.model.document.TestClassLite
```