# Hibernate Unable to load class []

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, tapestry

I recently added a few features (connecting database tables to other tables) using JPA (with hibernate). It worked fine before, but now I'm getting the exception `org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class []` - or at least I think that's the most relevant part of it. The whole exception is:

```
org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationException: 
org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.logAndRethrow(OperationTrackerImpl.java:186)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.run(OperationTrackerImpl.java:62)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.PerThreadOperationTracker.run(PerThreadOperationTracker.java:60)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.run(RegistryImpl.java:1254)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.StartupDefImpl.invoke(StartupDefImpl.java:48)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl$2.run(RegistryImpl.java:230)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.performRegistryStartup(RegistryImpl.java:361)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryWrapper.performRegistryStartup(RegistryWrapper.java:89)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.TapestryFilter.init(TapestryFilter.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.initialize(FilterHolder.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:852)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:298)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1349)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.startWebapp(JettyWebAppContext.java:297)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1342)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:741)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.doStart(JettyWebAppContext.java:366)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyServer.doStart(JettyServer.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:535)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:358)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyRunMojo.execute(JettyRunMojo.java:167)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.StartupDefImpl$1.run(StartupDefImpl.java:84)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.run(OperationTrackerImpl.java:56)
    ... 59 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:244)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:217)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:770)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:797)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:135)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSourceImpl.createEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerSourceImpl.java:224)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSourceImpl.getEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerSourceImpl.java:200)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSourceImpl.create(EntityManagerSourceImpl.java:293)
    at $EntityManagerSource_b8af25bcbdf4.create(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.jpa.EntityManagerManagerImpl.getOrCreateEntityManager(EntityManagerManagerImpl.java:80)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.jpa.EntityManagerManagerImpl.createAllEntityManagers(EntityManagerManagerImpl.java:70)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.jpa.EntityManagerManagerImpl.getEntityManagers(EntityManagerManagerImpl.java:61)
    at $EntityManagerManager_b8af25bcbdf3.getEntityManagers(Unknown Source)
    at $EntityManagerManager_b8af25bcbdf2.getEntityManagers(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.jpa.modules.JpaModule.startupEarly(JpaModule.java:187)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.StartupDefImpl$1.run(StartupDefImpl.java:70)
    ... 60 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class []
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:229)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.loadDriverIfPossible(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:183)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildCreator(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:139)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:78)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:217)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    ... 86 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:226)
    ... 97 more
```

As you might realize, I'm also using tapestry, but I guess that's irrelevant.

It's worth noting that the tables I connected already existed before (without the connections) and hence were already defined in `persistence.xml`.

I can't find the part in the code, in which I cause this exception and the message `Unable to load class []` doesn't help me much. Stepping into the decompiled classes didn't help either, so I'm running out of ideas here.

As I didn't find anything regarding this error message with an empty class name (in contrast to posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43578991/caused-by-org-hibernate-boot-registry-classloading-spi-classloadingexception-u)), maybe you can help me.

If you need any source code, I can write some code for you, that's similar to the original code, I can't however provide the original code itself. But as I mainly want an explanation of this exception message, this shouldn't be a problem.

---

**EDIT** This just got weirder: I reverted my local version to the last working state of our git repository, but the error remains. This must have to do something with Maven, I guess.

Comment: Can you publish an working example on Github?

Comment: @EugenCovaci I'm sorry but as it is a commercial software, this won't be possible. Except of course if you mean similar code? This would take a while tho

Comment: Yes, similar code.

Comment: Interesting problem but there are reasons for requesting [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). With this information it just is quite hard to help.

Comment: @pirho the problem is, however, that I don't know _what_ causes the error - if I knew, I wouldn't have asked. This means that I'll basically have to reduce the commercial code so often that it's _minimal_, but still throws the exception. Alternatively I could partially revert the changes I made, until I can identify the location of the problem. Both variants will take quite some while and if done, I'll have found the error. If it comes to this, I'll share my solution with you, however I'd be very happy, if someone could explain the exception to me in the meantime

Comment: I understand your problem. TTY to find the reason for ClassNotFoundException. What class is not found.

Comment: @pirho I don't know what you mean by _TTY_, but this is exactly my problem - I have no idea, what class can't be found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this was incredibly dumb.

I just forgot to build the entire project - I'd always used IntelliJs built-in *build* function, which works most of the times - but obviously not all the times. Anyway, if you ran into the same problem, try building your project before.