# Trying to run hql queries on intellij hibernate console

Tags: hibernate, jpa, intellij-idea, console, hql

The project is all setup and when i import the project the persistence detects the hibernate structure.

With each containing [image]

opening the console for a particular main opens up the console. 
Where i try to do a simple query it fails with the following error.

```
hql> select id from Way
[2020-02-11 18:02:48] org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class []
[2020-02-11 18:02:48] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
[2020-02-11 18:02:48]   at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
[2020-02-11 18:02:48]   at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
[2020-02-11 18:02:48]   at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:240)
[2020-02-11 18:02:48]   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.loadDriverIfPossible(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:200)
[2020-02-11 18:02:48]   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildCreator(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:156)
[2020-02-11 18:02:48]   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:95)
[2020-02-11 18:02:48]   at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
[2020-02-11 18:02:48]   at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
[2020-02-11 18:02:48]   at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
[2020-02-11 18:02:48]   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:260)
[2020-02-11 18:02:48]   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:94)
[2020-02-11 18:02:48]   at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
[2020-02-11 18:02:48]   at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
[2020-02-11 18:02:48]   at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
[2020-02-11 18:02:48]   at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1885)
[2020-02-11 18:02:48]   at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1843)
[2020-02-11 18:02:48]   at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1928)
[2020-02-11 18:02:48]   in HibernateFacadeImpl$MyRemoteConfigurationImpl.buildSessionFactory(HibernateFacadeImpl.java:38) (no stack trace)
```

I haven't done anything else with the IDE.

Comment: Try with fully qualified name of the Class (i.e with the package name)

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam still get the same error

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53523684/hibernate-unable-to-load-class ?

Comment: yes i have checked almost all the other questions..